# Strange line when looping through a csv file

Tags: java, android, file, loops

It should have reached the end of file, but it hasn't. 
Instead I'm getting this weird string which isn't an empty string nor does it appear to be spaces. Here's a picture of what I"m getting from the debugger.

[image: debug issue]

```
while ( (nextLine = csvReader.readLine()) != null && (nextLine != "")) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
while( (nextLine = csvReader.readLine()) != null && !nextLine.equals("")) {
...
}
```

Comment: Since Java 6, there is also `!nextLine.isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0):

I've always done this:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(file);
while(scnr.hasNext()) {
    ...
}
```

And I don't think I've ever had a problem like that.